# NodeJs and Protractor return a value from the shared file

Tags: node.js, protractor

```
this.queryMailApi = function(mailUrl, callback) {
  request.get({url: mailUrl}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    } else
    callback(body);
  });
};

this.myCallBack = function(data) {
  var emailData = data;
  console.log(emailData);
}
```

This is my function + callback to get the value. I want to return it to a function call similar to how you would do this.

```
var x = shared.queryMailApi(mailApiUrl, shared.myCallBack);
```

To be used later in code. I've read a ton of things about asynchronous Nodejs stuff which means I can't actually do this... but there has to be a way.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but I think you should be able to do this in in this way with a promise.

```
this.queryMailApi = function(mailUrl) {
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

  request.get({url: mailUrl}, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }

    deferred.resolve(body);
  });

  return deferred.promise
};


this
  .queryMailApi('example@mail.com')
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

If this doesn't work, you may take a look [webdriver.WebDriver.wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait). This may be useful.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.

Comment: @erics12512354 Did you try this?